# Error: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic, floating-point

I have written  a script to determine the Load average on the server as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

loadavg=`top -b -n1 | grep -i load | awk -F, '{print$4}'| awk -F: '{print $2}'`

if [ "${loadavg}" -le  1 ]
then
echo "OK - Load Average = ${loadavg} | Load_Average=${loadavg}"
exit 0;
elif [ "${loadavg}" -gt 1 ] && [ "${loadavg}" -le 2 ]
then
echo "WARNING - Load Average = ${loadavg} | Load_Average=${loadavg}"
exit 1;
elif [ "${loadavg}" -gt 2 ]
then
echo "CRITICAL - Load Average = ${loadavg} | Load_Average=${loadavg}"
exit 2;
else
echo "UNKNOWN - Load Average = NaN | Load_Average=NaN"
fi
```

When the script is executed, it displays following error:

```
./loadavg.sh
./loadavg.sh: line 5: [:  0.06: integer expression expected
./loadavg.sh: line 9: [:  0.06: integer expression expected
./loadavg.sh: line 13: [:  0.06: integer expression expected
UNKNOWN - Load Average = NaN | Load_Average=NaN
```

Comment: `top -b n1 | awk -F, '/load/ {print $4}'` is a lot cleaner...

Comment: How about `loadavg=$( cut -d' ' -f1 </proc/loadavg )` - and no, still not an **integer** expression. It's a fixpoint. If you want to use `-le` and friends, consider `cut -d' ' -f1 </proc/loadavg | cut -d. -f1`, i.e. just drop everything after the integer part.

Comment: Nagios alread has a check_load. Why are you making your own?

Comment: Do the whole thing in `awk`. `awk` can do floating points, `bash` or `[` cannot.

Comment: You can get the load from `uptime`, not need to run one iteration of `top` for that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Well spotted! I am doing this just for fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` (contrary to `ksh93` or `zsh`<sup>1</sup>) can't do floating point arithmetics. `awk` can though, so you can do the whole thing in `awk`.

Also, you don't need to use `top` (and wait 1 second) to get the load. The canonical way to get the load is from `uptime`.

```
uptime | awk '{load=+$(NF-2)}
  load > 2 {print "CRITICAL: " load; exit 2}
  load > 1 {print "WARNING: " load; exit 1}
  {print "OK: " load; exit 0}
  END {if (!NR) {print "UNKNOWN"; exit 3}'
exit
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In `zsh` though, you need to use the `(( loadavg > 2 ))` instead of `[ "$loadavg" -gt 2 ]` syntax for comparing non-integers</sup>

Comment: On Linux, looking up `/proc/loadavg` will be more economic than shelling out to `uptime`, albeit less portable.

Answer (score 2):

`top -b -n1 | grep -i load | awk -F, '{print$4}'| awk -F: '{print $2}'` returns nada, hence your errors.

Comment: `top -b -n1 | grep -i load` is displaying `top - 15:02:31 up 2 days, 23:15, 1 user, load average: 0.37, 0.42, 0.38`.

Comment: @MandarShinde, that depends on the `top` implementation. That also depends on whether there are processes with `load` in their name or username. Though you're right that it's not the problem the OP is facing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `loadavg` is null, causes syntax errors by `[`:

```
$ top -b n1 | grep -i load | awk -F, '{print$4}'| awk -F: '{print $2}'
<blank line here>
```

You must change it to:

```
$ top -b n1 | grep -i load | awk -F, '{print$4}'| awk -F: '{print $1}'
 0.24
```

However, you should use newer test in your script, it can handle this problem:

```
$ [[ "" -gt 1 ]] || echo "OK"
OK
```

With older `[`:

```
$ [ "" -gt 1 ] || echo "OK"
bash: [: : integer expression expected
OK
```

**Updated**

`bash` can not handle floating point numbers, so your comparison (even with new test `[[..]]`) will show errors.

You can use another tools to do this task, like `bc`, `awk`...

Example:

```
$ [[ $(echo "3 > 1" | bc -l) == 1 ]] && echo OK
OK
$[[ $(echo "3 < 1" | bc -l) == 1 ]] || echo Not OK
Not OK
```

Comment: `top -b -n1 | grep -i load | awk -F, '{print$4}'| awk -F: '{print $2}'` is printing `0.37` while `top -b n1 | grep -i load | awk -F, '{print$4}'| awk -F: '{print $1}'` prints `load average`. While the `top -b -n1 | grep -i load` output is `top - 15:02:31 up 2 days, 23:15,  1 user,  load average: 0.37, 0.42, 0.38`.

Comment: @MandarShinde: Yes, because you are parsing the output of `top`, it can produce different output. I tested in my Fedora machine. The main thing I want to show is you should using new test `[[..]]` instead of `[..]`.

Comment: When I replaced every `[` with `[[` and every `]` with `]]`, it displayed the error: `./loadavg.sh: line 5: [[: 0.00: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".00")`. Tested on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5.

Comment: @MandarShinde: `bash` can not understand float number, `bash` treat it as string, causing this error.

Comment: How should deal with this issue?

Comment: @MandarShinde: Updated my answer.

Comment: As said above, if you want to use floats with bash, use `bc` for example.

Answer (score 0):

First off, running top is more expensive than just grabbing "uptime".

```
$ uptime
 16:15:38 up 6 days, 23:22, 23 users,  load average: 0.99, 0.82, 0.70
```

Second, as @Stéphane Chazelas mentioned, bash doesn't like floating point arithmetic.

```
$ [[ "0.1" -lt 1 ]] 
bash: [[: 0.1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1")
```

Fortunately, bash expansion can take care of that.  From [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ```
>    ${parameter%word}
>    ${parameter%%word}
>          Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.   If
>          the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is
>          the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ``%'' case) or  the  longest  matching
>          pattern  (the  ``%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each
>          positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable sub-
>          scripted  with  @  or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the
>          expansion is the resultant list.
> ```

So it becomes pretty easy to strip out the decimal portions with "%.*"

```
$ la=`uptime | sed 's/.*average: \([0-9\.]*\).*/\1/'`
$ if [ ${la%.*} -lt 1 ]; then echo "OK - Load average is $la"; fi
OK - Load average is 0.42
```